# Difference of two Joda LocalDateTimes

Tags: java, jodatime

I've got 2 Joda `LocalDateTime` objects and need to produce a 3rd that represents the difference between them:

```
LocalDateTime start = getStartLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime end = getEndLocalDateTime();

LocalDateTime diff = ???
```

The only way I can figure is to painstakingly go through each date/time field and performs its respective `minus` operation:

```
LocalDateTime diff = end;

diff.minusYears(start.getYear());
diff.minusMonths(start.getMonthOfYear());
diff.minusDays(start.getDayOfMonth());
diff.minusHours(start.getHourOfDay());
diff.minusMinutes(start.getMinuteOfHour());
diff.minusSeconds(start.getSecondsOfMinute());
```

The end result would simply be to call `diff`'s `toString()` method and get something meaningful. For instance if `start.toString()` produces 2012/02/08T15:05:00, and `end.toString()` produces 2012/02/08T16:00:00, then `diff.toString()` would be the difference (55 minutes) and might look like 2012/02/08T00:55:00.

And, if this is a terrible abuse of `LocalDateTime`, then I just need to know how to take the time difference between the two and put that difference into an easy-to-read (human friendly) format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [org.joda.time.Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class for this - in particular the [fieldDifference](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#fieldDifference(org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,%20org.joda.time.ReadablePartial)) method.

Example:

```
LocalDateTime endOfMonth = now.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
LocalDateTime firstOfMonth = now.dayOfMonth().withMinimumValue();
Period period = Period.fieldDifference(firstOfMonth, endOfMonth)
```

Comment: I like Joda, but I am always overwhelmed. `Period` and `Duration`, sounds alike, but is quite different. I see the need, but it’s not always intuitive.

Comment: @MPi: Agreed. What's a `ReadablePartial`? Why do I need it to see whether a `LocalDateTime` was a certain amount of time ago? Agh!

Comment: Because Period could be a undefined absolute time. For instance, the Period between 14:35 and 15:36, which is a PartialReadable "time of day", will always be 1 hour and 1 minute.

Comment: The point is that a Period accounts for such things as daylight savings time;  a Period between two times may not always be what it seems that it should be, depending on the start/end datetimes chosen.  A Duration is simpler, it will always be a fixed exact amount of time.

Comment: [API Doc for Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)

Answer (score 10):

[Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) is better for some cases. You can get a "timezone-independent" duration for use with LocalDateTimes (in local time line) by this trick:

```
public static Duration getLocalDuration(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
    return new Duration(start.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC), end.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by using following steps:

1. Take two LocalDateTime objects as Start and End
2. Convert both of them to Instant object such as `start.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);`
3. Calculate the Duration using `Duration.between(instant t1, instant t2)`
4. Convert it into nanoseconds or milliseconds or seconds using various conversion methods. Nanoseconds can be calculated as `Duration.toNanos()`

I have provided a full example below.

```
public long getDuration(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {

    //convert the LocalDateTime Object to an Instant 
    Instant startInstant = start.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);         
    Instant endInstant   =   end.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    //difference between two Instants is calculated
    //convert to nano seconds or milliseconds 
    long duration=Duration.between(startInstant, endInstant).toNanos();

    return duration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printTimeDiffJoda(final String start, final String end) {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        try {
            // Parse datetime string to org.joda.time.DateTime instance
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(format.parse(start));
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(format.parse(end));

            System.out.println("Joda Time API - Time Difference ");
            System.out.println("in years: " + Years.yearsBetween(startDate, endDate).getYears());
            System.out.println("in months: " + Months.monthsBetween(startDate, endDate).getMonths());
            System.out.println("in days: " + Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays());
            System.out.println("in hours: " + Hours.hoursBetween(startDate, endDate).getHours());
            System.out.println("in minutes: " + Minutes.minutesBetween(startDate, endDate).getMinutes());
            System.out.println("in seconds: " + Seconds.secondsBetween(startDate, endDate).getSeconds());
            System.out.println();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

By http://www.luyue.org/calculate-difference-between-two-dates/