# Difference between two dates using the JODA Library

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I have two DateTime instances and i would like to find out the exact difference between them.
I am using the following

```
DateTime dt = DateUtils.convertFromString(user.getUpdated());
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
Hours hours = Hours.hoursBetween(now, dt);
```

This off course only gives me the Hours between the two dates. I need the complete values like X Day y hours and z minutes. How can i do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318154/difference-of-two-joda-localdatetimes

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Period`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html):

```
Period period = new Period(now, dt);
```

You can provide a [`PeriodType`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html) which specifies exactly which units you want.

(If `dt` was in the past, you probably actually want `new Period(dt, now)` instead, to give a positive period.)