# java comparator for two LocalDateTimes

Tags: java, time, jodatime, comparator

A custom class called `MyCustomClass` has a property that it s joda `LocalDateTime`.  I need to create a `java.util.Comparator` class to compare instances of `MyCustomClass` by their `TimeStamp` property, which is of type `LocalDateTime`.  I have read several postings on this (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318154/difference-of-two-joda-localdatetimes)), and I have tried all the methods, but none of the methods shown in the answers seem to work.  For example, the following several approaches throw compilation errors:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.Period;

import my.app.model.MyCustomClass;

public class MyCustomClassComparator implements Comparator<MyCustomClass>{
    public int compare(MyCustomClass mcc1, MyCustomClass mcc2) {
        //this first attempt throws a return type error for the method.
        return Period.fieldDifference(mcc2.getTimestamp(), mcc1.getTimestamp());
        //This next attempt says that LocalDateTimes are not valid arguments
        Duration.between(mcc2.getTimestamp(), mcc1.getTimestamp());
        //The next approach also says LocalDateTimes are not valid arguments.
        DateTime.parse(mcc2.getTimestamp()), mcc1.getTimestamp()).getSeconds();
        //This boilerplate approach says the minus sign is not valid for LocalDateTime
        return mcc1.getTimestamp() - mcc2.getTimestamp();
    }
}
```

I intend to use this elsewhere in code like:

```
List<MyCustomClass> mccs = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
// Sort by time stamp:
Collections.sort(mccs, new MyCustomClassComparator());
```

How do I write a `Comparator` class to compare instances of `MyCustomClass` based on their Joda `LocalDateTime` properties?

Comment: Isn't `LocalDateTime` already `Comparable`?  Can't you just use `mcc1.compareTo(mcc2)`?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764106/comparing-two-dates-using-joda-time

Comment: Or do away with the `Comparator` altogether...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Caveat: Can only do away with `Comparator` if `MyCustomClass` implements `Comparable<MyCustomClass>` with same comparison.

Comment: @Andreas Not sure I understand. The only need for a `Comparator` is if the default implementation of the `Comparable` isn't what you want, but I can't see anywhere the OP is doing something special about the with their comparision

Comment: @MadProgrammer OP is not sorting `DateTime`'s, but `MyCustomClass`'es *by* a `DateTime` field.

Comment: @Andreas Ahhh...Then we need more information ;)

Answer (score 12):

If all you need is a comparator instance:

Similar to [Iłya Bursov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864275/i%c5%82ya-bursov)'s answer, because LocalDateTime implements comparable, you can use [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Comparator.comparing(MyCustomClass::getTimestamp)
```

Answer (score 6):

[LocalDateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) implements [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, so you can implement comparator like:

```
public class MyCustomClassComparator implements Comparator<MyCustomClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final MyCustomClass mcc1, final MyCustomClass mcc2) {
        return mcc1.getTimestamp().compareTo(mcc2.getTimestamp());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that Comparator is a functional interface, we could have it with a single lambda expression.

```java
Comparator<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeComparator = (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2);

//Then use the comparator as always....
LocalDateTime minDate = dates.stream()
                             .min(localDateTimeComparator)
                             .orElseThrow(Assertion::Error)
```

For reuse, a static instance could be helpful

```java
//interfaces are "more static" than classes with "static members" ;-)
public interface MyDateUtils { 

   Comparator<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeComparator = (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2);

}
```